# Set button outside view

Tags: swift

How can i set an button outside the view you will see?
So you generate unique coordinates, but outside the screen. Than i can animate the button from that position to the middle.

I have this code to generate coordinates

```
var p = CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%1000),y:Int(arc4random()%1000))
```

This is working, but i want to get random coordinates outside the screen or in other words what the user sees.

Comment: BaseZen and I have covered your question completely, just mix it up and you are done mate :-)

Answer (score 1):

What about something like that?

```
func generateRandomPointOutsideOfViewBounds (view: UIView) -> CGPoint{
    var min: UInt32 = UInt32(view.frame.size.width)
    var max: UInt32 = UInt32(1000)
    let randomX: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(max - min) + min

    min = UInt32(view.frame.size.height)
    max = UInt32(1000)
    let randomY: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(max - min) + min

    return CGPointMake(CGFloat(randomX), CGFloat(randomY))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply manipulate the `frame` property:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame

```
var myButton: UIButton // initialized somehow

// at appropriate time. Idiomatic place is in layoutSubviews() of your custom UIView subclass, but this may be triggered by an action, especially if you're following up immediately with animiation -- up to your design
myButton.frame = CGRect(p, myButton.frame.size)

// now call your animation
UIView.animateWithDuration(/* ... parameters ... */,
    animations: { myButton.frame = /* resting location */ },
    completion: { /* ... */ })
```

**EDIT**

Looks like the two answers thus far (at 8/17 12:46 EST) are covering completely separate aspects of your question, which is apparently ambiguous. Taken together they answer the whole thing.

Comment: Hi, Base, your answers right, but he asked about how to randomly generate a CGPoint outside of a UIViews bounds... :-) Or did I understand you wrong? @da1lbi3